# How can I set my own bookmarks in a PDF?

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader

I would like to save several bookmarks in a PDF document I'm reading, so that each time I open the PDF, I could re-browse to certain locations. How can I do this? Ideally, I would be able to assign each bookmark its own name.

I'd like an answer for Adobe Acrobat Reader, but if it's not possible in that program, a solution in any program would be acceptable.

Answer (score 10):

All I did was a basic web search (google, bing, yahoo, etc.) for "pdf modifier free" and this came up within the first 5 hits.

PDF-XChange Viewer <-- click link)for Windows XP/Vista/7.
Best part: **It's FREE!**

http://download.cnet.com/PDF-XChange-Viewer/3000-10743_4-10598377.html

I did give it a go and here's what I found:

- **BOOKMARKS -** YES! You can clear the current bookmarks (e.g., usually chapter
  markers) and put your own in.  What I choose to do was insert my own
  "Chapter" marker (i.e., bookmark) at the top of all the other
  bookmarks and call it "My Bookmarks". Then, within PDF-XChange Viewer
  I can both view the PDF, use the Bookmarks, and add/delete/change my
  personal bookmarks.
- **OCR -**  *WOW!*  I can scan printed documents in with my scanner (300 DPI minimum) and use PDF-XChange Viewer to OCR the the scanned pages to English, German, Spanish, French or nearly 20+ other languages (which may require the PRO version).
- **REDACTION -**  Use the Rectangle tool to "redact" information, e.g., cover text or images with a black rectangle.  I used the ability to create my own rctangle "style" of a black solid line and fill rectangle.

**Note:** To truly (legally) "redact" information you may need to either export the PDF as a TIFF (sadily, each page) then import (or print) those images to a new PDF or physically print the PDF to paper.   If you choose to use an app (such as PrimoPDF or CutePDF) to "print" the PDF to a new PDF, consider setting a master password to diable the "copying" of text from within the new PDF.  However, do know that the text will actually still be "in" the PDF but have the black rectangle above it, making it difficult to read. Printing a PDF to a new PDF (via PrimoPDF or CutePDF) and securing the document from copying of text ***MAY NOT*** meet legal requirements for a true legal "redacting" of information.

So, for free, PDF-XChange Viewer has a good amount of tools to give you power over the PDF.

FYI ~ I'm not realted to Tracker Software, the company who makes PDF-XChange Viewer, in any way. Just a normal person (like y'all) looking for economical tools (free works best!) to get things done.

It's That Simple.  Really.

Answer (score 7):

In Acrobat Reader, you can use a comment(sticky note) or text highlight as an alternative to bookmarks.
You will then be able to jump to comments from the Comment panel.

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can do this in Adobe Pdf Reader!!

Way to do this-->
The small 5KB JavaScript file is packaged in a downloadable ZIP file at PDF Hacks.
Link:
http://www.pdfhacks.com/bookmark_page/

1.Download,unzip,copy to C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 10.0\Reader\Javascripts.
(for Linux: /home/[user]/.adobe/Acrobat/[version]/JavaScripts, test with 9.0 and 8.0.)

2.Open any PDF file with Adobe Acrobat Reader and open the View menu. Four new items are clearly visible under the menu – Bookmark this page, Go to bookmark, Remove bookmark and Clear bookmarks.

Happy Bookmarking!!!

Comment: I used this myself and it worked fairly well...  My preferred method is to just upload it to Google Play Books and run it from there, then the bookmark is available on any of my devices anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Foxit Reader](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/Secure_PDF_Reader/). It allows you to add bookmarks that stay after you have closed the file.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any PDF viewer that will allow you to create bookmarks stored externally of the pdf file itself that will remain the next time you open the pdf file in that viewer.  What you would need to do is edit the PDF

Adding bookmarks to a PDF that stays with the file requires software capable of editing a PDF, such as the full version of Acrobat (not Reader).  There are any number of other software apps for editing PDF files.  There is one freeware piece of software that I've heard of, but never used, called [JPdfBookmarks](http://www.freewaregenius.com/2010/05/24/how-to-add-bookmarks-to-a-pdf-document-using-free-software/), that is specifically designed to allow you to add bookmarks to a PDF file.

Comment: Preview on the Mac lets you do bookmarks external to the PDF.  Foxit Reader supposedly does as well too (untested).

Comment: there are many android PDF viewers that allow you to bookmark your place

Answer (score 1):

I've made a folder in "My Documents" for PDFs.  I have included in this folder a notepad page for bookmarks: In the PDF folder, right click on the blank space, click *New » Text Document*.  Title it "Bookmarks".

When I want to create a bookmark, I highlight and copy a few words of text in the PDF where I want to resume reading, and paste them into the Notepad page beneath where I have previously typed the PDF title. Any number of PDFs and bookmarks may be accommodated in this way.

When I want to resume reading, I highlight and copy the same few words of text from the "Bookmarks" Notepad page and paste them into the search box (having previously typed `Ctrl-F`) in the PDF in Adobe Reader. A click of the forward arrow and I am there again.

Describing this makes it sound complicated, but after the folder and notepad are set up, it quickly becomes very easy. I do wish simple bookmarks were already available in Adobe Reader X, though.

Answer (score 0):

Preview will allow such things on the Mac.  [FoxIt Reader](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/reader/features_benefits.php) supposedly does as well, but I haven't used it in years so I can't comment for sure.

Good luck getting anything accomplished with Reader. I did find this on [eHow](http://www.ehow.com/how_10082_create-bookmarks-pdf.html), but I gave up using such crap from Adobe long ago.

Answer (score 0):

Acrobat Reader doesn't permit users to create bookmarks.  You'll need Acrobat Professional or some other PDF editor for that task, not a PDF reader.

If you're the creator of a document, or the author has granted permission to modify it, you can then create bookmarks.

To lead readers through a document, authors can also define '[Read articles](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/pro/using/WS58a04a822e3e50102bd615109794195ff-7c8f.w.html)'.

Answer (score -1):

There's no such thing as shown in Adobe reader perhaps in Acrobat. Anyway what you do is go to view at top of page, click comment, go to right and click annotations. A side bar opens up. Now here's the good part, scroll to the page you want to serve as a bookmark and hit the thought bubble icon in annotations. Click anywhere on page and type the text aka bookmark title you want then it'll save it for you in the comments list and you'll see the page numbers with your text title index. Congrats you just made an adobe reader bookmark

Comment: This was answered by @Radu previously.

Answer (score -1):

SumatraPDF.

It is free, fast and reads everything. The bookmarks work as you describe plus every time you open the program you are greeted with a custom page of pinned and frequent documents for easy access.

Comment: could u elaborate ur answer,i guess sumatrapdf can read only pdf