# Is there any tool where I can mark the pages of a pdf to be printed when viewing the pdf?

Tags: windows, pdf, printing

I would like to print certain pages of a pdf. But I haven't the exact page numbers of that pdf. Instead I only have some points from the structuring of that pdfs content which don't correspond with the pdf page numbers. So I would like to view that pdf and mark the pages I would like to be printed. When I have finished I would like that  the marked pages get printed.

Does anyone know of such a tool?

Comment: What tool are you using to read the pdf?

Comment: @Raystafarian Currently it's either Adobe Reader or Foxit Reader.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I use Acrobat Pro and can use *Bookmarks* to bookmark pages and then just print all from the bookmarks menu. See [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/X/pro/using/WS42C7616C-A8BD-4192-B095-657271A277ED.w.html).

Adobe reader does not inherently have the bookmarks toolbar since Reader X, I think. [Here](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4526085) is a thread on that discussion, as well as a sticky note solution that I'm not too confident in using for printing.

[This SU thread](https://superuser.com/questions/260366/how-can-i-set-my-own-bookmarks-in-a-pdf) discusses several options as well. Like [PDF-XChange Viewer](http://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer)

The foxit website is down right now, but I believe it has built in bookmarks, so you may be able to print from those similar to Acrobat.